# How can i create custom shape widget in flutter? which is dynamically render in all mobile devices

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]I want to add a custom profile avatar to one of my projects. I tried with the custom painter & clipper. But, when I test in different devices the shape & size are not as my designer gave to me.

[image]

This is my painter class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ProfileBox extends CustomPainter {
 @override
 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
 final paint = Paint();
 paint.color = Colors.grey;
 paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
 final path = Path();
 path.moveTo(25, 4);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, -4, size.width - 25, 4);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - 10, 10, size.width - 4, 25);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(
 size.width + 4, size.height / 2, size.width - 4, size.height - 25);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(
 size.width - 10, size.width - 10, size.width - 25, size.height - 4);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(
 size.width / 2, size.height + 4, 25, size.height - 4);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(10, size.height - 10, 4, size.height - 25);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(-4, size.height / 2, 4, 25);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(10, 10, 25, 4);
 canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
 }
 @override
 bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
 return this != oldDelegate;
 }
}
```

This is my clipper class.

```
import 'package:invoice_app/constants/globals.dart';
class ProfileClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
 ProfileClipper({@required this.profileSize});
 final ProfileSize profileSize;
 @override
 Path getClip(Size size) {
 final path = Path();
 path.moveTo(23, 2);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, -4, size.width - 23, 2);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - 8, 8, size.width - 2, 23);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(
 size.width + 4, size.height / 2, size.width - 2, size.height - 23);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(
 size.width - 8, size.width - 8, size.width - 23, size.height - 2);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(
 size.width / 2, size.height + 4, 23, size.height - 2);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(8, size.height - 8, 2, size.height - 23);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(-4, size.height / 2, 2, 23);
 path.quadraticBezierTo(8, 8, 23, 2);
 return path;
 }
 @override
 bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

And, I'm using it in UI with the below widget.

```
 painter: ProfileBox(),
 child: Container(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
 height: 100,
 width: 100,
 child: ClipPath(
 clipper: ProfileClipper(profileSize: ProfileSize.smallProfile),
 child: Container(
 // if image url is null and want to display icon or svg then add padding
 padding: _imageFile != null
 ? const EdgeInsets.all(0)
 : const EdgeInsets.all(13),
 // color: Colors.blue,
 child: Image(
 // if image url is null then display icon or svg
 image: _imageFile != null
 ? FileImage(_imageFile)
 : AssetImage(
 'assets/defaultbusiness.png',
 ),
 fit: BoxFit.fill,
 ),
 ),
 ),
 ),
 ),
```